# Create an Excel Spreadsheet (XSLX) in C# -- server side

Tags: c#

So, this question has been asked before, but wait -- it's not a duplicate! (at least I don't think so).

I need to create Excel files (xlsx files).  The library must be suitable to run on a server, it must be 64-bit capable,

*and* I have to be able to distribute it with a closed-source (for profit) product.

I had been hoping to use ExcelPackage on CodePlex, but it's published under GPL, and as nearly as I can tell, without the "component library exception", so I'm pretty sure that means I can't use it.

Can anyone recommend a good, server-compatible, 64-bit library that I can use in my closed-source app?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's 64-bit, but Aspose Cells might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used GemBox.Spreadsheet in a 64bit environment(and am still using it).
http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheet.htm

It's pretty fast, easy to use and when we purchased it it was the cheapest one to do it. Have not checked the prices afterwards.

It has royalty free deployment.

ps: your question only says c#, I have used it with c# on asp.net, iis6 and iis7

Answer (score 1):

I have always cheated using html. Just output it as an xslx and excel will handle the conversion.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
     <tr><td> cell A1</td><td> cell B1</td></tr>
     <tr><td> cell A2</td><td> cell B2</td></tr>
  </table>
 </body>   
</html>
```

As mentioned above I have used Aspose Cells and it has worked well in 64bit [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx)

Comment: yes, this will work for simple tables. However, if you really want to interact with the spreadsheet (create excel functions, dynamic ranges, create excel files based on templates etc.) you need something with a bit more bite

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't seem to work -- I tried copy/pasting your example into notepad, saving as test.xlsx.  On open, Excel 2007 displays an error indicating that the file is corrupted or in an incorrect format.

Comment: Been a while since I have tested. I used it on a intranet site in company that disabled Extension Hardening. Here is why it's not a good idea in your situation.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Comment: That would do it.  I'll have to go the 3rd-party route.